# Authenticating GeoServer REST calls with certificates?

Tags: geoserver

To meet security requirements, our project needs to move our GeoServer credentials(account/password) out of the code base. Is it possible to authenticate REST calls with certificates, or any other method besides account/password credentials?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 'yes'!

Exactly how requires working out a few details.  If all users are required to provide a certificate, you'll likely want to sort that out at the container level (Tomcat, Wildfly, etc).

Once GeoServer has a certificate, you'll likely want to set up a role service to map users to roles.

The docs for GeoServer's security system are great.  I've read them multiple times, and I'd strongly encourage checking them out:  http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/index.html#security

Since you mentioned certificates, I'd suggest reading this tutorial: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/tutorials/cert/index.html.

Since you mentioned security REST endpoints, I'd point out 
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/rest.html.  I believe some of that configuration can be done through the GeoServer admin UI.

As a note, GeoServer is highly modular; you may need to install a module or two to connect to an LDAP server or modify how the security settings, etc.